# Where clause of Sql - may it read a stale data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause, multi-user

I have a simple table (SQL Server) with **one** row, and many users can
access this row.

If the first user does:

```
Update Table1 
Set Balance = Balance +10
Where FirstName= 'John' //The value in this column is "John" indeed.
```

Is it possible, that Balance will be updated by this first user, although an other user has entered and changed FirstName to "Dan" AFTER the row with
FirstName = "John" was found by first user  but BEFORE the changing of balance was done by first user?

I mean:

1. The Where clause of the first user found the row with FirstName = "john"
2. The second user entered, and change FirstName to "Dan".
3. Continue from #1, the balance was updated by the first user, because the first user doesn't know that a second user has changed something (The Where clause has found the row already before the second user did something).

Comment: (1) Your code is not valid SQL Server code.  (2) If someone starts using things like `NOLOCK` in their queries, then yes, stale data might be read.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your comment. Lets say that no one uses NOLOCK, am I assured that this situation can not happen? I mean, every Update command implements Lock by default?

Comment: in sql server it is not possible

Comment: Please run `DBCC useroptions` and post the results.  We need to see the default transaction isolation level

Comment: @SteveC Thank for teaching me this command (DBCC useroptions). The isolation level is read committed.

Comment: Then the simple answer is 'no' it's not possible

Comment: @SteveC I think It little bit contradicts the optimistic concurrency issue, because if I get this automatic lock, then there is no problem that many users will just do the updates as   balance=balance+10 (if 7 users do it, can we be sure that the balance will grow in 70?)

Comment: The lock occurs (hopefully if your code is quick) for only a brief fraction of a second.  The db completes transactions after the lock is released.   Under heavy load all systems break down.  Which link of the chain breaks depends on many things including hardware and networking.  Test to see what level result in NOT getting 70 from 7 updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows are locked when they are being modified (and `NOLOCK` won't work in an update statement so you don't have to worry about that).

So:

1. First user comes along and updates the balance for John + 10.
2. Second user updates the row and changes the name to Dan, if the first user has not committed yet, the second user will wait until the +10 balance has been committed.
3. First user commits
4. Second user commits
5. Balance is +10 and the name is now Dan.
6. If First user fires another statement for John then they won't find a row so nothing gets updated.

If the first user fires the same update between 2 and 3 then the update will be successful as they still have the necessary row lock.

Comment: So you say that isolation level has nothing to do with it? and NOLOCK can not change this behavior?

Comment: Yes. Try it for yourself, you can make your transactions longer using begin transaction and commit explicitly when you are ready. In order to corrupt the data, instead of using an update statement like you've shared, you would split the atomic update into a select then update (using information from the select as basis for your update).